# curl linkage errors

Tags: curl, linker

I'm building a C++ project using curl in Visual Studio 2008. I get linker errors for every curl function I'm using:
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _curl_multi_add_handle referenced in function

As mentioned in the FAQ section 5.7 in http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#Link_errors_when_building_libcur
I'm linking against static libraries, and have specified CURL_STATICLIB in the PreProcessor definitions, but still I face the same problem. It is as if the static libraries are not there, even though I have specified the lib directory containing the static libs in my project library path.
What else can one do? Please help before I shoot myself.

Answer (score 0):

Goddammit, I did not specify the library name in the Additional libraries option.